# Android Studio how to have a permanent variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, variables, global-variables

I want to create a class that has a variable, that this variable can be modified and obtained from other activities and this varable always be saved.

I've tried to do this class with the variable "TipoAnuncio":

```
public class Filter_Object  {
    private String TipoAnuncio ="Perdidos";

    public String getTipoAnuncio(){
        return TipoAnuncio;
    }
    public void setTipoAnuncio(String TipoAnuncio){
        this.TipoAnuncio = TipoAnuncio;
    }
}
```

And i've tried to get and to set this variable from other Activities, for example:

```
public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Filter_Object filter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);


        Log.i("anuncioahora", filter.getTipoAnuncio());
}
}
```

An error appears which says :`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.julianrc1.petracecitm/com.example.julianrc1.petracecitm.fragments.Intents.FilterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.julianrc1.petracecitm.Objects.Filter_Object.getTipoAnuncio()' on a null object reference`

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you need to initialize `filter`: `filter = new Filter_Object();`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `static` variable. Example: `public static String TipoAnuncio = "Perdidos";`

Access/modify it as: `Filter_Object.TipoAnuncio`